# Hikashop Characteristics not changing image, content or price in browsers

Tags: hikashop

I have characteristics for volume/size setup for my product and have them displayed as radio buttons on the product page:

https://cotsperfumery.under-development.info/shop-online/ladies-fragrances/product/english-rose-eau-de-parfum

Each Variant in the backend has its own settings for image, price, description, title, etc.

When I view the page in Firefox all is working fine -- selecting different volumes changes all the on-page details, image, price, etc. However changing the characteristics using Safari, Chrome or Explorer on Mac and PC does not change anything on the page.

I reverted the template overrides before posting to ensure it was not a mistake in my override and got the same result in all browsers.

Looking at the page code across the browsers, in all the browsers apart from Firefox, it appears the `<form>` code is somehow removed. If I manually add in the form element via dev tools it then works!

Answer (score 0):

On Linux + Chrome the site seems to work ok: selecting another size changes the price/image/description. However, on Linux in Firefox I can reproduce your issue: the price/image/description don't change. Even in incognito/privacy mode (to make sure the issue is not browser plugin related).

I noticed a lot of **errors in the Console** (Chrome: F12 to inspect the page, check the "Console" tab).

Could you disable Joomla's `System - HTTP Headers` plugin to test if your issue is related to the **Content Security Policy** (CSP). I have a feeling that your **CSP might be too strict** and that it does not allow the visitor's browser to load some of Hikashop's JavaScript files which it needs to change the price/image/description.

Comment: pe7er, Thank you for your reply, most appreciated. I have turned off the HTTP Headers, but still it fails to work in Chrome, Safari or Edge!